# How can I solve a frequently-deadlocked MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-deadlocks

Assume a MySQL table called, say, `results`. `results` is automatically updated via cron every day, around 11AM. However, `results` is also updated from a user-facing front-end, and around 11AM, there are a lot of users performing actions that also update the `results` table. What this means is that the automatic cron and the user updates often fail with 'deadlock' errors.

---

Our current solution:

We have implemented a try/catch that will repeat the attempt 10 times before moving on the next row. I do not like this solution at all because, well, it *isn't* a solution, just a workaround, and a faulty one at that. There's still no guarantee that the update will work at all if the deadlock persists through 10 attempts, and the execution time is potentially multiplied by 10 (not as much of an issue on the cron side, but definitely on the user side).

Another change we are about to implement is moving the cron to a different time of day, so as to not have the automatic update running at the same time as heavy platform usage. This should alleviate much of the problems for now, however I still don't like it, as it is still just a workaround. If the usage patterns of our users changes and the platform sees heavy use during that period, then we'll encounter the same issue again.

---

**Is there a solution, either technical (code) or architectural (database design) that can help me alleviate or eliminate altogether these deadlock errors?**

Comment: I don't know why it would deadlock on one table.
But if there's a series of tables involved, you want to access them all in the same order so that if you have something locked you know everyone else who access that would have to be in line waiting for the same order.

Comment: What table engine are you using for the results table.  You can find this by doing a 'show create table results;'

Comment: how many records in that table?  I've seen strange deadlocks on 1 million records.

Comment: Currently there are ~450,000 rows in the table. The table engine is InnoDB. I'll admit my above example was simplistic, there are in fact multiple tables involved in the process. It's a process that I myself am not 100% familiar with (it was made by another developer who's no longer here).

Comment: try updating with ORDER by so that you don't have updates in reverse order of another update.

Comment: To get rid of dead locks make sure all processes follow the same order if they for example need to access/update tables A,B,C make sure no other processes try to access/update C,A, instead switch the order so that it access/update A,C.  This way whoever gets A first finishes and the others will access A, and no possibility of someone holding C while waiting for A since to have C they must have A already if they needed it

Comment: @JeffRichards, deadlocks can occur only in transactional storage engines. Practically, for MySQL this means InnoDB only.

Comment: @Forbs, that makes no sense that deadlocks occur spontaneously when a table has over 1 million rows. I've used tables with billions of rows without deadlocks. I've never heard of a case where the number of rows increases the chance of a deadlock. More likely your table got large enough that some queries were taking too long, and had a greater chance of overlapping with concurrent sessions.

Comment: Correct, the queries were taking too long, it started happening at 1 million.  That's why I mentioned it

Comment: @Forbs, then it was your code that was already susceptible to deadlocks, regardless of the number of rows. Your original comment made it sound like any querying of a table with 1+ million rows would lead to a deadlock, which is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deadlocks happen when you have one transaction that is acquiring locks on multiple rows in a non-atomic fashion, i.e. updates row A, then a split-second later it updates row B.

But there's a chance other sessions can split in between these updates and lock row B first, then try to lock row A. It can't lock row A, because the first session has got it locked. And now the first session won't give up its lock on row A, because it's waiting on row B, which the second session has locked.

Solutions:

- All sessions must lock rows in the same order. So either session 1 or 2 will lock row A, the other will wait for row A. Only after locking row A does any session proceed to request a lock for row B. If all sessions are locking rows in ascending order, then they will never deadlock (descending order works just as well, the point is that all sessions must do the same).
- Make one atomic lock-acquiring operation per transaction. Then you can't get this kind of interleaving effect.
- Use pessimistic locking. That is, lock all resources the session *might* need to update in one atomic lock request at the beginning of its work. One example of doing this broadly is the `LOCK TABLES` statement. But this is usually considered a hinderance to concurrent access to the tables.

You might like my presentation [InnoDB Locking Explained with Stick Figures](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/innodb-locking-explained-with-stick-figures). The section on deadlocks starts on slide 68.

Comment: Thanks, this is just the kind of answer I was looking for. Informative about the subject and helpful in solving it!